# Exporting webpage as PDF

Tags: asp.net, pdf

I'm trying to export a PDF from an asp.net webpage that has a master site. Please note that I am not using a grid view, I just want to export the page itself.

Here is what I currently have:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=TestPage.pdf")
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
Dim sw As New StringWriter()
Dim hw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
Me.Page.RenderControl(hw)
Dim sr As New StringReader(sw.ToString())
Dim pdfDoc As New iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.A4, 10.0F, 10.0F, 100.0F, 0.0F)
Dim htmlparser As New HTMLWorker(pdfDoc)
PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream)
pdfDoc.Open()
htmlparser.Parse(sr)
pdfDoc.Close()
Response.Write(pdfDoc)
Response.[End]()
```

The errors message I'm getting is:

The UNC path should be of the form \server\share.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: The UNC path should be of the form \server\share.

```
Source Error: 


Line 46:             PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream)
Line 47:             pdfDoc.Open()
Line 48:             htmlparser.Parse(sr)
Line 49:             pdfDoc.Close()
Line 50:             Response.Write(pdfDoc)
```

Any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use some third party dll like "itextsharp.dll" which is free. you can use that for below code.

```
Public Overrides Sub VerifyRenderingInServerForm(control As Control)
    ' Verifies that the control is rendered 

End Sub

Protected Sub btnExport_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    If gridview.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Dim sw As New StringWriter()
        Dim htw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)

        gridview.RenderControl(htw)

        Dim mem = New MemoryStream()

        Dim document As New Document(PageSize.LETTER, 50, 50, 50, 50)
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, mem)

        document.Open()

        Dim hw As New iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker(document)
        hw.Parse(New StringReader(sw.ToString()))
        document.Close()

        Response.ClearContent()
        Response.ClearHeaders()
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + DateTime.Now)

        Response.BinaryWrite(mem.ToArray())
        Response.[End]()
        Response.Flush()
        Response.Clear()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I was NOT using a Gridview, but it has worked and allowed me to download the file, so thank you for that but it isn't able to open it.

Comment: I have update the above code and user "itextsharp.dll" which is free.